# Android 4.0 Telephony API with blacklist for phonenumber

Tags: android

Since android 2.3 Google has deleted -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54

But on Android telephones 2.3 and up to 4.0 - there is a function to "add phone to blocklist". Is there any way to add phonenumber programatically to blacklist without using rejection of `ITelephony.aidl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to reject a call is to cut it. And the only way to cut it to use **ITelephony.aidl**.

Another way to switch the phone to airplane mode and back.

So you can design an app with a listener for incoming calls. Compare that incoming call phone number with a possible black listed database and then take an appropriate action on a match.

Comment: Ok, but how Google makes it through operating system? As I read somewhere they have such opportunity on the level of operating system but only for manufactures...(

Comment: The System app's have access to all the resources in the system. When we write our own app, we are limited by the API's provided to us by google. AIDL's are one way to bypass and tap into calls otherwise hidden from us.

Comment: and what is for - http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/ ??? As I understand I can make my app - SYSTEM APP...

Comment: This is only possible on rooted and unlocked phones. Many users dont even know what it means and people usually dont o for it as it voids warranty. Only enthusiasts and hackers go for rooting. So u may end up in a situation that your app may not be useful to a large community.

Comment: All my droid phones were rooted... and for my goal this app may not be useful for a large community. So, if I'll make app with AIDL as a systemApp - will it work on android 2,3 and up?

Comment: Absolutely! I did that for an App of my own and faced no problems whatsoever, go for it!