# how to add/remove phone number to auto reject list programmatically in android

Tags: android, phone-call

I develop a simple app can reject incoming calls for android phones . And I can do it successfully in my app.

But still , i want to learn that is it possible to add/remove a phone number to auto reject list programmatically  for android phones?

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740858/android-4-0-telephony-api-with-blacklist-for-phonenumber

Answer (score 1):

For detecting the call and getting the calling number, try using PhoneStateListener:
http://chetanandroidarora.wordpress.com/2011/12/25/listener-for-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android-example/

and for rejecting the call, try take a look at this Stackoverflow question:
[How to reject a call programatically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393654/how-to-reject-a-call-programatically-android)

Comment: Hi, as i said, i can get calling number and can reject a call programmatically. What i want to learn is to add a phone number to auto reject list in android.

Comment: Like this just programmatically? [link](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-block-phone-calls-on-your-android-smartphone/)

Comment: Yes. I just want to learn, if it is possible to add a phone number auto reject list programmatically? Not reject it with coding.

Comment: @cergun did you find the answer, i am looking for the same thing. Actually the problem i am facing with self launching is the mili second delay before the call was terminated.